# How does one access data posted within restify 1.x.x?

Tags: rest, node.js, post

I'm posting data to a restify API, but cannot find any currently examples for how to access the posted data. How does this work?

Answer (score 47):

I found the answer. One of the included plugins needs to be activated,  `restify.bodyParser`. The data may then be found in either `req.params` (default) or `req.body` (`mapParams: false`), depending on the [settings](http://mcavage.github.com/node-restify/#Bundled-Plugins) (look specifically at BodyParser section).

Example:

```
server.use(restify.bodyParser({ mapParams: false })); // mapped in req.body
```

Or:

```
server.use(restify.bodyParser()); // mapped in req.params
```

Answer (score 7):

For `restify 5.0.0+`, use:

```
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());
```

https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/1394#issuecomment-312728341

For older versions use:

```
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
```

After telling restify to use the `bodyParser` middleware the request body will be available on the request objects body property:

```
server.post('/article', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Is very simple:

```
server.use(restify.bodyParser({ mapParams: false }));
```

You need to activate the bodyParser in restify

Answer (score 1):

This code will print the request body to the console:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer();

// This line MUST appear before any route declaration such as the one below
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

server.post('/customer/:id', function (req, resp, next) {
  console.log("The request body is " + req.body);
  response.send("post received for customer " + req.params.id + ". Thanks!");
  return next();
});
```